# vue-i18n $t with values attribute is not translating

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I am trying to import a .json file to use as the translation file.

```
<template>
    <template v-slot:footer>
      <div>{{ $t('menu.file.new.label', $i18n.locale, locale) }}</div> <--Issue outputs menu.file.new.label
    </template>
</template>

<script>
import locale from '@/locales/modules/messaging.json'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      locale: locale
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

the locale from messaging.json does not have any errors and works if i instead added the following to the top

`<i18n src="@/locales/modules/messaging.json"></i18n>`

and changed the function parameters to exclude `$i18n.locale` and `locale` and it works. Unfortunately, this is not an option as i want to pass the data to a grandchild component. However, if i can configure the grandchild to use their grandparents translation data that works too..

how can i get either:

1. The above to work
2. Alternatively, use the grandparents translation data in the grandchild
3. Alternatively, dynamically import translation data in the grandchild based on a prop(location of translation file to be imported)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution

```
<template>
  <st-age v-bind:menus="menu" v-bind:locale="locale[$i18n.locale].menu">
    <template v-slot:content>message: {{ $route.params }}</template>
    <template v-slot:footer>
      <div>{{ $t('menu.file.label') }}</div>
    </template>
  </st-age>
</template>

<script>
import menu from './menu'
import locale from '@/locales/modules/messaging.json'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      menu: menu,
      locale: locale
    }
  },
  i18n: {
    messages: locale
  },
  components: {
    'st-age': () => import('@/components/layout/stage/container')
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

`locale[$i18n.locale].menu` is passing the translation data i actually need and not the entire object(which works too)

in the child component, i just pass this data as a prop to the grandchild

in the grandchild i

```
 mounted() {
    this.$i18n.setLocaleMessage(this.$i18n.locale, this.locale)
  }
```

where `this.locale` is the translation data and `$t('file')` yields whatever i set as `en.menu.file` in the global translation data originally imported

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should create a plugin like below:

src/plugins/i18n.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

const DEFAULT_LOCALE = 'en';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: yourLocale || DEFAULT_LOCALE, // set locale either from localStorage or config
    fallbackLocale: DEFAULT_LOCALE,
    messages: require('messages.json'), // set locale messages
    sharedMessages: require('other.json if exist'),
    silentFallbackWarn: true,
});

export default i18n;
```

Then call it from main.js to globalize:

```
import i18n from './plugins/i18n.js';
...
new Vue({
    i18n,
    router,
...
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Then if you want to go on with custom messages, you can set it with i18n block like:

```
<script>
data(){
...
}
methods: ...
i18n: {
 messages: require(your json path....)
}
</script>
```

Then you can call it like:

```
$t('test');
```

Comment: Im using nuxt so im using the nuxt-i18n which registers it as a module

Comment: tried adding the imported json to `i18n: { messages: locale }` didnt work

Comment: Per: `https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/api/#vue-injected-methods` i should be able to set translation values and it will return the correct translation but it doenst work